# iPhone shows element with Bootstrap hidden-xs class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an element on my site with the `hidden-xs` class on it. When I load it on my iPhone, the element still shows up.

On [Slacre.com](http://www.slacre.com), the cover photo has `hidden-xs` applied to it, and the top-nav isn't using its mobile form.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Add the viewport meta tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Try [Bootlinting](https://github.com/twbs/bootlint) your site beforehand next time. It catches this error.

Comment: @cvrebert is Bootlint available as a rails gem? I can't seem to find it. Or is there another way of installing it on a RoR application?

Comment: @MoonMan No gem. But the in-browser version is just a single JS file: https://github.com/twbs/bootlint#in-the-browser